# How to insert a row into a table and update the last row before inserting the new row in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, insert-update

Here is structure of my table CustInfo

```
 Cm_ID | Cust_ID  | StartDate   |   EndDate        | Status 
   1   |   1020   |  05/09/2013 |   20/09/2013     |    Off
   2   |   1027   |  16/09/2013 |   **31/12/2099** |    **On**
   3   |   1020   |  21/09/2013 |   31/12/2099     |    On
```

I want to do that whenever I will insert a new row for Cust_ID=1027 It should first update the [EndDate] to new [StartDate] i.e Today and Set [Status]='Off'.

After inserting new row it should look like this

```
 Cm_ID | Cust_ID  | StartDate   |   EndDate        | Status 
   1   |   1020   |  05/09/2013 |   20/09/2013     |    Off
   2   |   1027   |  16/09/2013 |   **30/09/2013** |    **Off**
   3   |   1020   |  21/09/2013 |   31/12/2099     |    On
   4   |   1027   |  01/10/2013 |   31/12/2099     |    On
```

I have done this using 2 different queries as follows.

```
Update CustInfo SET EndDate = '30/09/2013' ,Status='Off'
WHERE Cm_ID=(SELECT MAX(Cm_ID) FROM CustInfo WHERE EndDate='12/31/2099' AND Cust_ID=1027)

INSERT INTO CustInfo ([Cust_ID], [StartDate], [EndDate], [CurrentStatus])
VALUES(1027,'01/10/2013','12/31/2099','On')
```

Now i want to do this using a single query or a Stored Procedure. But I dont know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably better off using a trigger, this way the logic is applied to all `INSERT`s rather then relying on people using an SP. Also it would be better to execute the `UPDATE` after the `INSERT` i.e. only when the `INSERT` succeeds.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgCustInfo_Status
ON CustInfo
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @id INT

  SELECT @id = Id 
  FROM (
    SELECT Id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Id DESC) rn 
    FROM CustInfo
  ) t
  WHERE rn=2

  UPDATE CustInfo
  SET EndDate = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE),
      Status = 'OFF'
  WHERE Id = @id
END
```